# shell: colorize log output

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to color output text.

I mean, I'm getting logs:

```
[pod/hes-mpi-fhir-api-2-4p55p/hes-mpi-fhir-api] {"time": "2021-05-27 09:14:02,641", "level": "INFO", "trace_id": "0", "source": "c.u.f.j.s.r.ResourceReindexingSvcImpl:390", "message": "Loaded 16229 resources for reindexing in 466ms"}
[pod/hes-mpi-fhir-api-2-4p55p/hes-mpi-fhir-api] {"time": "2021-05-27 09:14:02,649", "level": "ERROR", "trace_id": "0", "source": "c.u.f.j.s.r.ResourceReindexingSvcImpl:581", "message": "Failed to index resource SearchParameter/20003/_history/2: ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.UnprocessableEntityException: SearchParameter.status is missing or invalid ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.UnprocessableEntityException: SearchParameter.status is missing or invalid    at ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.dao.r4.FhirResourceDaoSearchParameterR4.validateSearchParam(FhirResourceDaoSearchParameterR4.java:106) ~[hapi-fhir-jpaserver-base-5.4.0.jar!/:na]    at ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.dao.r4.FhirResourceDaoSearchParameterR4.validateResourceForStorage(FhirResourceDaoSearchParameterR4.java:82) ~[hapi-fhir-jpaserver-base-5.4.0.jar!/:na]  at ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.dao.r4.FhirResourceDaoSearchParameterR4.validateResourceForStorage(FhirResourceDaoSearchParameterR4.java:47) ~[hapi-fhir-jpaserver-base-5.4.0.jar!/:na]  at ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.dao.BaseHapiFhirDao.updateEntity(BaseHapiFhirDao.java:1103) ~[hapi-fhir-jpaserver-base-5.4.0.jar!/:na]   at ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.dao.BaseHapiFhirResourceDao.reindex(BaseHapiFhirResourceDao.java:1283) ~[hapi-fhir-jpaserver-base-5.4.0.jar!/:na]    at ca.uhn.fhir.j
```

I'd like to color first header like. Somethink like this:

**[pod/hes-mpi-fhir-api-2-4p55p/hes-mpi-fhir-api]** {{"time": "202...}

Is there anyway to get this?

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminals text can be colored using ANSI codes. You just have to insert them before and after `[...]`:

```
sed $'s/^/\033[31m/;s/]/]\033[m/' yourLogFile
```

[image: output]

- `\033[31m` starts red color.
- `\033[m` disables all color.
- We need C-style strings `$'...'` so that these escape sequences are interpreted.
- `sed s/abc/xyz/` replaces the first occurrence of `abc` with `xyz`.
- Multiple `s/…/…/` can be combined using `;`.
- `^` is the beginning of a line.

Comment: Could you explain what each part is for? What should I do in order to highlight for example a `"ERROR"` token?

Comment: @Jordi I added explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="] {"; def="\x1B[m"; red="\x1B[31m"; yellow="\x1B[33m"}{printf("%s%s] %s{%s%s\n",red,$1,yellow,$2,def)}' log.txt
```